# Optional chaining question mark after function name

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have read [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) chapter of apple's The Swift Programming Language(swift2). In this chapter, there is no mention about an optional question mark **after** a function name but before the left parenthesis.

But I saw the following swift code from [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID6) Apple's document (the 'Delegation' section):

```
 //There is a question mark right after 'window'
    if let fullScreenSize = myDelegate?.window?(myWindow, willUseFullScreenContentSize: mySize) {
        print(NSStringFromSize(fullScreenSize))
    }
```

What does it mean of having a question mark after a function name but before the left parenthesis ?

Comment: See my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECoptionalProtocol and http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECsuppressing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two situations in which this it used:

- A protocol method is itself marked `optional`, so we don't know whether the adopter of the protocol implements this method.
- We are sending a message to an AnyObject. We can send *any* known class message to an AnyObject — it throws away type-checking — but then, again, we don't know whether the actual object implements this method.

So this question mark means to send this message *optionally* and *safely*. If it turns out that the recipient does *not* implement it, don't send the message, and return nil. If the recipient *does* implement it, send the message, but now we have to wrap any result in an Optional (because otherwise we could not return `nil` in the first case).

Behind the scenes, Objective-C `respondsToSelector:` is being called. Hence, this pattern is available only if the recipient is exposed to Objective-C. Basically, this is an Objective-C language feature expressed in Swift shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the case of so-called "failable initializers". That's when you want to provide a type for which initialization can fail under some conditions like invalid initialization parameter values or a required external source. “A failable initializer creates an optional value of the type it initializes" (The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.5)). One typical example is the `String` type initializer `init?(data: Data, encoding: String.Encoding)` that initializes a `String` value from a `Data` byte buffer. If the provided `Data` can't be decoded using the selected encoding value (e.g. UTF-8) the initialization will fail and it will return `nil`.

See https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID224

Answer (score 0):

This is used when a protocol method is optional and might not be implemented on the object. (In this case, the optional `window:willUseFullScreenContentSize:` method from the `NSWindowDelegate` protocol)